# Three mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability

Three events $E$, $F$, and $G$ cannot occur simultaneously. It is known that
$$P(E F) = P(F  G) = P(E  G) = \frac{1}{3}.$$
What is the value of $P(E)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are those given probabilities $1/3$? Please edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: [Inclusion-Exclusion-Principle?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E$, $F$, and $G$ can't all occur simultaneously, then these events $EF$, $EG$, and $FG$ are essentially mutually exclusive (the probability of the intersection of any two of them is zero). You'll need to argue that, but it's pretty quick. So then since each of $EF$, $EG$, and $FG$ also have probabilities of $\frac{1}{3}$, they are essentially exhaustive (meaning that there's probability 1 of being in exactly one of them). So being in $E$ has the same probability as being in $EF\cup EG$.  And since being in $EF\cap EG=EFG$ is probability zero, you can finally conclude that $P(E)=P(EF)+P(EG)$.

Comment: *If $E$, $F$, and $G$ can't all occur simultaneously, then these events $EF$, $EG$, and $FG$ are essentially mutually exclusive.* $\quad$ Just pointing out this claim is true by Definition 1 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4632982/21813), but not by Definition 2. This doesn't affect your argument, since the parenthetical point that you note is the relevant premise for the remainder of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Draw a $3$-circle Venn diagram with circles representing $E$, $F$, and $G$.  Fill in the triple intersection with $0$ (probability).  Then see what other regions you can fill in with the given set difference probabilities.